# How to send link include id in email user in django?

Tags: python, django

please  i need to help  i send this lien http://127.0.0.1:8000/benevole/demande_participer/id:?/
in email user but id is not Read in email

Thanks in advance

```
---this is the urls.py

 path('benevole/demande_participer/<int:id>', views.demande_participer, name='demande_participer'),
```

------  this is views.py =>

```
def demande_participer(request,id):



    participers=Mission.objects.get(id=id)
    benParticiper=User.objects.filter(username=request.user)

    template=render_to_string('Association/email_template.html')
    email=EmailMessage(
                'Veuillez confirmer  votre participation a la mission proposer',#header message
                template, # h1
                settings.EMAIL_HOST_USER,
                [request.user.email], 
                )
    email.fail_silenty=False
    email.send()
```

---this is email_template.html

```
{% load crispy_forms_tags %}
{% block content %}
Confirmé la Participation


http://127.0.0.1:8000/benevole/demande_participer/id:?/

{% endblock %}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to pass the context to the render to string method, let's say you want the participers id in the email link

**views.py**

```
def demande_participer(request,id):
    participers=Mission.objects.get(id=id)
    benParticiper=User.objects.filter(username=request.user)

    # Context here
    context = {
        "participers": participers,
    }

    # pass context in render_to_string
    template=render_to_string('Association/email_template.html', context=context)
    email=EmailMessage(
                'Veuillez confirmer  votre participation a la mission proposer',#header message
                template, # h1
                settings.EMAIL_HOST_USER,
                [request.user.email], 
                )
    email.fail_silenty=False
    email.send()
```

--------email_template.html-------

```
{% load crispy_forms_tags %}
    {% block content %}
    Confirmé la Participation
    
    <!-- in your Html {{participers.id}} -->
    http://127.0.0.1:8000/benevole/demande_participer/{{benParticiper.id}}/
    
    {% endblock %}
```